# Python, ООП, установка параметров сеттером

Tags: python, ооп

[image: Скриншот компилятора]В классе Room  установил параметры объектов по у молчанию на None, затем, при создании объекта, хочу назначать их с помощью метода setRoom, однако при выполнении кода значения параметров не изменяются, а так и остаются None.

Исходный код ниже:

```
class Room:

    def __init__(self, l=None, w=None, h=None):
        self.l=l
        self.w=w
        self.h=h

    def setRoom(self):
        self.l=input('etner lenght')
        self.w=input('etner wigth')
        self.h=input('etner height')

    def getSqr(self):
        return 2*self.h*(self.w+self.l)

    def getNewSqr(self):
        return print('New square of room: ',Room.getSqr()-WD.sqrCount)

    def getNumRul(self):
        return print('You need ',Room.getNewSqr()/Oboi.getSqrOboi(),' rulonov of oboi')

class WD:

    sqrCount=0

    def __init__(self,NumOfWD=None,lwd=None,hwd=None):
        self.NumOfWD=NumOfWD
        self.lwd=lwd
        self.hwd=hwd

    def setWD(self):
        self.NumOfWD=input('etner NumOfWD')
        for i in range (self.NumOfWD):
            self.lwd = input('etner lenght of WD')
            self.hwd = input('etner height of WD')
            WD.sqrCount+=self.lwd*self.hwd

    def getSqrWD(self):
        return WD.sqrCount

class Oboi:

    def __init__(self,lo=None,ho=None):
        self.lo=lo
        self.ho=ho

    def setOboi(self):
        self.lo=input('etner lenght of oboi')
        self.ho=input('etner heoght of oboi')

    def getSqrOboi(self):
        return self.lo*self.ho

R=Room()
R.setRoom()

wd=WD()
wd.setWD()

Ob=Oboi()
Ob.setOboi()

print('Square of room:',R.getSqr())
R.getNewSqr()
R.getNumRul()
```

Comment: `input` возвращает тип `str`, нужно выполнить приведение к типу `int` а после уже совершать мат операции, и все заработает как нужно.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч
Благодарю, совсем забыл про это.